# Locating World War 1 burial or cremation records in Turkey

Tags: death-records, world-war-1, burial-records, turkey

I have this confirmed death record:

[image]

> TRUCKLE, SIDNEY, Reg. No. 2873. Rank, Private, Royal Munster Fusiliers, 6th Batt.; killed in action, Gallipoli, August 15, 1915; born Woodford, Wiltshire.

Thus, we know that Sidney Allen Truckle (my Great Great Uncle) died in the First World War in Gallipoli, Canakkale, Turkey. Or, as another record puts it "Dardanelles".

Is it possible to locate a burial or cremation record for him? For that matter, even a death register.

I have obtained the documents I can find from fold3.com.

Comment: Sidney Allen Truckle was my Great Uncle, Favourite Brother of my Grandmother my dad was named after him Sidney Allan Coule, His name is also on the Helles Memorial

Comment: @MrGrahamACoule Yes, I have the details about the Helles Memorial. Awesome that he is your Great Uncle. He is my Great Great Uncle!!! My ancestry is through his brother Robert Frank Truckle who died at the young age of 38.I have no photos of my Great Grandfather or his siblings but I do have a single photo give to me of their parents Henry and Fanny.  I have a total of 7 sisters of Sidney of my tree so one of them must be your Grandmother. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to the [Commonwealth War Graves Commission](https://www.cwgc.org/) site (which should be your starting point for any Commonwealth military burial), it will tell you that he is commemorated on the Helles Memorial, along with 20957 other soldiers. There is no burial register or grave.

There is also a memorial inscription for him at Woodford in Wiltshire. See [War Memorials Online](http://warmemorialsonline.org.uk/memorial/217917).

His death is recorded in the GRO Death Army Other Ranks (1914 To 1921) Index available on FindMyPast and you should contact the [GRO](https://www.gro.gov.uk/gro/content/certificates/) to find out how to order a copy of the death certificate.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have also managed to locate some if that info here: https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/56022257/sidney-truckle. But i was able to obtain a nice certificate at the CWGC site. You mention Woodford in Wiltshire. I was born in Wiltshire. Where can I find info about this local memorial inscription so I can visit?

Comment: I can see the FMP entries but don't have a paid subscription to obtain the GRO ref.

Comment: Contact the GRO (by phone, ideally) to find out what information they actually need to provide the certificate. Name and date of death may be sufficient.  I'm not willing to breach the FMP ToS to do a lookup.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the link to WMO. It is moving to see "S TRUCKLE" on there and to think he is a relative of mine. Once the Lockdown dur to COVID-19 is over I might see if I can visit the church.

Comment: GRO Death certificates for WW1 are, I believe, almost never worth the cash. My understanding is that they will give no more detail than you would find on the CWGC site - probably less. In particular, the place of death is likely to just be the theatre of war. They were produced some years after to give closure to relatives and presumably provide a final legal statement of death.